# Display images in ListBox

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, listbox

I loading various images in run time and I want to show them in list box (small images, then the user should click on one of them and show him in real size).

My code is:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    int imageNumber = 0;
    public List<String> ImagePath = new List<String>();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        lb_Images.ItemsSource = ImagePath;
    }

    private void bu_addImage_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        addImageToListBox();
    }

    private void addImageToListBox()
    {
        imageNumber++;
        if (imageNumber == 4) imageNumber = 0;
        string directoryPath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;

        // load input image
        string ImageFilename = directoryPath + "img";
        ImageFilename += imageNumber.ToString();
        ImageFilename += ".jpg";

        ImagePath.Add(ImageFilename);
    }
}
```

and the xaml is:

```
<Window x:Class="forQuestionWPF.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="216" Width="519">

    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="ImageGalleryDataTemplate">
            <Grid>
                <Border BorderBrush="#FFFF9800" BorderThickness="1"  Width="120" Height="120" Padding="5" Margin="5" CornerRadius="6">
                    <!--Bind Image Path in Image Control-->
                    <Image Source="{Binding ImagePath}" Stretch="Fill"  HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                        <!--View Large Image on Image Control Tooltip-->
                        <Image.ToolTip>
                            <Grid>
                                <Image Source="{Binding ImagePath}" Stretch="Fill" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="200" Width="200"></Image>
                            </Grid>
                        </Image.ToolTip>
                    </Image>
                </Border>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>

        <ItemsPanelTemplate x:Key="ImageGalleryItemsPanelTemplate">
            <!--Display Images on UniformGrid Panel-->
            <UniformGrid Rows="1" Columns="25" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    
    <Grid>
        <Canvas Height="177" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="canvas1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="497">
            
            <ListBox Canvas.Left="6" Canvas.Top="5" Height="166" Name="lb_Images" Width="441"
                     BorderBrush="{x:Null}" DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource ImageGalleryDataTemplate}}"
                     ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource ImageGalleryItemsPanelTemplate}}">
            </ListBox>
            
            <Button Canvas.Left="453" Canvas.Top="26" Content="Add" Height="64" Name="bu_addImage" Width="38" Click="bu_addImage_Click" />
        </Canvas>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I know that the list box updated when I add image path to the list because if I debug I found some items under `lb_Images.items`, but I show nothing.

Comment: is it Windows form application?

Comment: @HackerMan wpf application

Comment: i see now,,i was trying it on win forms....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**`Some notes`**

- DataContext for `ListBox` it's not necessary, then you set ItemSource. Instead of set the `ItemTemplate`
- In DataTemplate remove the `{Binding ImagePath}`, instead of write `{Binding}`, because in this case the elements of the DataTemplate inherit `DataContext`.
- When you add new items to `ListBox.Items`, you must call `ListBox.Items.Refresh()` or use the [`ObservableCollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms668604%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), because:

> ObservableCollection represents a *dynamic* data collection that `provides notifications` when items get added, removed, or when the whole list is refreshed.

Try this example:

**`XAML`**

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ImageGalleryDataTemplate">
        <Grid>
            <Border BorderBrush="#FFFF9800" BorderThickness="1"  Width="120" Height="120" Padding="5" Margin="5" CornerRadius="6">
                <Image Source="{Binding}" Stretch="Fill"  HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                    <Image.ToolTip>
                        <Grid>
                            <Image Source="{Binding}" Stretch="Fill" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="200" Width="200" />
                        </Grid>
                    </Image.ToolTip>
                </Image>
            </Border>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>

    <ItemsPanelTemplate x:Key="ImageGalleryItemsPanelTemplate">
        <UniformGrid Rows="1" Columns="25" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <Canvas Height="177" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="canvas1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="497">

        <ListBox Canvas.Left="6" Canvas.Top="5" Height="166" Name="lb_Images" Width="441"  
                 ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ImageGalleryDataTemplate}"
                 ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ImagePath}">
        </ListBox>

        <Button Canvas.Left="453" Canvas.Top="26" Content="Add" Height="64" Name="bu_addImage" Width="38" Click="bu_addImage_Click" />
    </Canvas>
</Grid>
```

**`Code-behind`**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    int imageNumber = 0;
    public List<String> ImagePath = new List<String>();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        lb_Images.ItemsSource = ImagePath;
    }

    private void bu_addImage_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        addImageToListBox();
    }

    private void addImageToListBox()
    {
        imageNumber++;
        if (imageNumber == 4) imageNumber = 0;
        string directoryPath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;

        // load input image
        string ImageFilename = directoryPath + "img";
        ImageFilename += imageNumber.ToString();
        ImageFilename += ".jpg";

        ImagePath.Add(ImageFilename); 

        lb_Images.Items.Refresh();
    }
}
```